# apache loads externally but not locally

Tags: apache-http-server, ip, webserver, domain, xampp

I just recently upgraded my internet and Comcast sent me a new router/modem in one; the ARRIS TG1682G.  I thought I was having all sorts of issues port forwarding with this router until I took a minute to try from my phone and found out it was forwarding the ports.  But on my local machine when ever I try to load my IP or domain I have set up for my IP, I get an error as if the page does not exist.

I have flushed my DNS, cleared all my cache, tried multiple browsers, checked my host file, and ran ccleaner.  Yet I am still unable to locally navigate to my IP.  I can get to my domain using a proxy, but as you can imagine this is not ideal.

My domain is set up at http://its.dirtrif.com (please verify that works for you in your response)

**Additional Requested Information**

I have XAMPP set up on my local machine and I can navigate to it using localhost or my local ip (10.0.0.92).  I have port forwarded port 80 on my modem and set up a sub domain that points to my public IP (noted above), and even though I can get to the domain on my mobile device (not on my local network) I can not load the domain on my local machine, or any other machine connected to the network (wifi / ethernet).

I've never used wireshark before but I filtered the port and  navigated to my ip in the browser this is the results in wireshark after navigating to my IP once `http://i.imgur.com/lwvY2rJ.png` `http://i.imgur.com/rVT1O9f.png` (sorry for it being screenshot I couldn't figure out how to get the text for every one) and honestly I have no idea how to interoperate any of that this is what I see in my browser `http://i.imgur.com/n2kOGRW.png` and through a proxy it works `http://i.imgur.com/SbKhhcY.png`

**UPDATE**

I have posted this issue on another forum and a response I got was "the issue might be that the router does not support NAT loopback"  I am looking into this now.

**How can I get my IP (domain) to work locally, when it is working externally?**

Comment: I clicked our link, "Working". What do you mean get it to work locally? Work or view? Please clarify how you are testing your domain. Are you using a local server and reading your page on localhost? Or do you mean that your domain is not accessible from your browser and you think it's your modem/router/comcast? Where is your index.html/htm/php page located? On a hosted server or your own machine where the DNS points to your ISP's public IP? All kinds of scenarios come to mind. Please specify.

Comment: Added additional information to the OP, I believe that covers everything.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now. And to be extra clear, the index lives exactly where? So, 'its' is your subdomain yeah? Here is something I have played with before that might be causing your issues, try its.dirtrif.com and dirtrif.com/its; the first will work if you have "masking" enabled. And they don't both act the same when requesting them on your browser FYI.

Comment: @DrCustUmz Can you run wireshark and filter port 80 traffic on the LAN, perhaps the router is sending the packets back on your network with the public ip address which the web server would drop. Maybe try adding 10.0.0.92 as a secondary ip address on the Apache server.

Comment: @ejbytes the index is on a second hard drive, x://xampp/htdocs/www  the subdomain is not the issue, i cant even get anything to load with my direct IP address I.E. 88.888.888.88 (which is all the domain is pointing to, I just gave you guys a domain so I wasn't posting my IP.  I am using my IP though.

Comment: @user3623501 I'll give that a shot and report back

Comment: @user3623501 I've never used wireshark before but I filtered the port and  navigated to my ip in the browser this is the results in wireshark after navigating to my IP once http://i.imgur.com/lwvY2rJ.png http://i.imgur.com/rVT1O9f.png (sorry for it being screenshot I couldn't figure out how to get the text for every one) and honestly I have no idea how to interoperate any of that this is what I see in my browser `http://i.imgur.com/n2kOGRW.png`

Comment: @DrCustUmz Sorry, I actually meant for you to add your public ip address as your secondary ip address on the apache box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modem/router in question does not support NAT loopback.  A way to get around this would be to point the device IP to the domain via the host file although this is not ideal.

Example:

```
 10.0.0.92 its.dirtrif.com
```

Better off purchasing my own router/modem and get rid of the Comcast provided one, plus save 10$ on my bill every month.

After reading a bit about them the [ARRIS SURFboard SBG6900-AC](http://www.walmart.com/ip/ARRIS-SURFboard-SBG6900-AC-Cable-Modem-with-AC1900-WiFi-Router/49843892) seems to be a solid choise.